# Cannot switch to radeon graphics card on HP Pavilion g7 1019eg on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, 18.04

I'm trying to switch from my integrated Intel graphic to my Radeon 6470m. I'm on my laptop model HP Pavilion g7 1019eg.

I used [this text](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics#Default_GPU) with no luck

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation 
    Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
    [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff)

The GRUB is configured to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeo.modeset=1" 

vga_switcheroo is enabled (TESTED)
```

The current state of the Hybrid Graphic is :

```
0:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0

1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

I solved some root issues and when I type

```
sudo echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch or 
sudo echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

nothing happens and the state is the same.

Comment: The state is correct. You can use `DRI-PRIME` to switch graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, so i'll write here:

use `DRI_PRIME=1 *command*` if you want to run some apps with Radeon GPU.

But if you seeking permanent switch, i don't know and i'd like know too.